# Magento 1.9 - After Export Products, Category few columns values like 000,000,000

Tags: category, csv, export, magento1.9.2.3

After export products, category few columns like 12,223,234,544,348,000,000,000   what is mean 000. How to view what category it is?

**FYI** - few products assigned to more than one category like 6 or 7 categories.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV0XP.jpg

File : https://we.tl/t-F2HsGD2bma

Comment: share here CSV screenshots, please and csv file too.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Pls check with my updated post

Comment: it is issue for when you download it and then open then please make sure a start no recovery and recovery options. okay then it works proper.

Comment: from where you export products? from default Magento admin

Answer (score 0):

Please do one thing. because of 1,324,4556,7 is count as number so.
Whenever you export the all categories make it separator with "|" instead of ",".

I hope it is useful for you.